# overflow-y:auto attribute in plain HTML ignores children height

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want a scrollable list of items within a div element. I use display:
`flex; flex-direction: column; overflow-y: auto`
The element within the div have a fixed height. As the elements sum of fixed height, I would expect the scrollbar to appear. Instead, the elements shrink to fit. by docs, that is not intended. If I use min-height instead of height, it works as intended, but that is not the purpose of min-height and height in my opinion. Safari and Chrome show the same behaviour. Do I something wrong?  Here the example with height set to 20, the sum is 100 and the list is 80pix height, no scrollbar:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Overflow demonstration</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div style="width: 100px; height: 70px; border: 2px solid black; display: flex; flex-direction: column; overflow-y: auto;">
      <div style="height: 20px; background-color: red;"></div>
      <div style="height: 20px; background-color: blue;"></div>
      <div style="height: 20px; background-color: green;"></div>
      <div style="height: 20px; background-color: yellow;"></div>
      <div style="height: 20px; background-color: purple;"></div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Here the same, now working as I use min-height instead of height:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Overflow demonstration</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div style="width: 100px; height: 70px; border: 2px solid black; display: flex; flex-direction: column; overflow-y: auto;">
      <div style="min-height: 20px; background-color: red;"></div>
      <div style="min-height: 20px; background-color: blue;"></div>
      <div style="min-height: 20px; background-color: green;"></div>
      <div style="min-height: 20px; background-color: yellow;"></div>
      <div style="min-height: 20px; background-color: purple;"></div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

I do not want to have that as a special case in my code. What do I or the browser wrong?

Comment: Flex items are _allowed_ to shrink by default, if you do not want that, then you need to apply `flex-shrink: 0` to them.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding `flex-shrink: 0;` to all the child elements.

Because flex allows items to shrink to fit and in this example you dont want that to happen.

Btw. you can add `flex-grow: 1;` so if the container is to big the items automatically grow to fit, if you need that.